# Android: Permission Denial: requires android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, android-permissions

I know there are quite a few postings out there concerning this very issue, yet I was not able to fix it yet.

So what I have is basically a very small app, containing little more than a VideoView widget. When deployed to the emulator, everything is fine. When I try to do on-device testing, I receive an exception, basically

```
 Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
 cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000
 cmp=jfl.projects.fk/.StartupActivity } from null (pid=3903, uid=2000) requires
 android.permission.INTERNET
```

Well, having read that error message i stuffed the Manifest with as much permission-tags as I possibly could (well, one at a time, each time the last didn't solve anything), but, yeah, guess what. 
So, these are the permissions I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

within the manifest-Tag

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

as qualifier for the application- as well as for the activity-Tag

The manifest is basically just that. The activity has nested an intent-filter tag defining

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

but that's it.

Any idea who feels neglected here and desperately longs for internet permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of `android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"`. That is indicating that the home screen, or anything else that tries launching your activity, needs that permission.

The AndroidManifest.xml file  element should contain:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

If you are using Eclipse and click on AndroidManifest.xml, select the Permissions tab and click 'Add' and select 'Uses Permission' and select the 'android.permission.INTERNET' permission.

The Eclipse AndroidManifest.xml view's 'Application' tab has a 'Permission' pulldown menu -- DON'T use that.  (It is a misleading field)

Comment: Cool, that was easy. Thank you very much, and excuse this propably pretty stupid question.

Comment: @Romiox: You aren't the first to make that mistake, and I doubt that you will be the last. Between `<permission>`, `<uses-permission>`, and `android:permission`, it can get rather confusing.